# Find string like 0-9 or plus or space or hypen in T-Sql?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

At the moment I have it as

```
Example like '[0-9+ ]' OR Example like '%-%'
```

is it possible to have this in 1 like statement? or there is a good resource anywhere, where i can read up instead of having to ask possibly stupid questions?

Thanks

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can combine all in the one `LIKE` operator as `LIKE '%[0-9+ -]%'`

Possible options of `LIKE` usage can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx